# Spring MVC Unit Testing - Mocked Service method is not called

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test, mockmvc, spring-mvc-test

I was working on a spring boot project where I have controller which calls a service method and process the output.

I'am using spring MockMvc for testing the web layer. In my test class I have mocked the service method with Mockito.when(). But when I call the corresponding handler method it is not calling the mocked service method instead returns a null response.

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class SocialLoginEndpoints {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("facebookAuth")
  SocialLogin faceBookAuth;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("googleAuth")
  SocialLogin googleAuth;

  @Autowired SignupService signupService;

  @GetMapping("/auth/google")
  public String googleAuth(@RequestParam String signupType, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "redirect:" + googleAuth.getAuthURL(request, signupType);
  }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@WebMvcTest(SocialLoginEndpoints.class)
class SocialLoginEndpointsTest {

  @Autowired MockMvc mockMvc;
  MockHttpServletRequest mockHttpServletRequest;

  @MockBean GoogleAuth googleAuth;

  @MockBean FacebookAuth facebokAuth;

  @MockBean SignupService signupService;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    mockHttpServletRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
  }

  @Test
  void googleAuth() throws Exception {
    Mockito.when(googleAuth.getAuthURL(mockHttpServletRequest, "free"))
        .thenReturn("www.google.com");
    mockMvc
        .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/auth/google").param("signupType", "free"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.redirectedUrl("www.google.com"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isFound())
        .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());

    Mockito.verify(googleAuth, Mockito.times(1)).getAuthURL(mockHttpServletRequest, "free");
  }
```

The reponse which is returned is

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 302
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Language:"en", Location:"null"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stubbed `googleAuth.getAuthURL` incorrectly.

The `MockHttpServletRequest` you create in your test and use during stubbing is not the same instance as `HttpServletRequest` that is sent via `MockMvc`. Also, they are not equal to each other (`Object.equals` is used as it is not overriden)

By default Mockito uses equals to verify if arguments in a stubbing match those in the real call. Your stubbing params do not match call params, thus a default value for the method (null) is returned.

The simplest way to fix is to relax argument matchers.

```
Mockito.when(googleAuth.getAuthURL(
                 any(HttpServletRequest.class), 
                 eq("free")))
       .thenReturn("www.google.com");
```